# Shared dependency property update issue in binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a read-only dependency property which is  shared  between two WPF classes. So I made this property shared property. While binding this property on XAML, It takes its default  value and can't be updated. But If I use the main owner of this property, its value can be updated.

So what is your advice?

```
public  class A
{
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey XPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("X", 
        typeof(Point), typeof(A), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(0, 0),  
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits | 
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty =  
        RelativeMousePointPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public Point X
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(XProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XProperty, value); }
    }

    public void SetRelativeMousePoint(Point point)
    {
        SetValue(XPropertyKey, point);
    }
}

public class B
{ 
    //I use this class for binding
    public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty = 
        A.XProperty.AddOwner(typeof(B));

    public Point X
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(X); }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of adding the property as a owner in class b? Without the Key you can't set it. Remember just adding it as an owner doesn't built any kind of relationship between class A and B. You property X on class B can't do anything. What do you want to achieve? Why does it need to be shared?

Comment: I need to get the value of X in class B but X  has to be read-only property.

Comment: Bs X property doesnt have a value, and will never have one what value do you want to read from it? You are saying "B you can have the X property(not its value!!) from A, but can't set it to any value" and again, remember the value of the property in an instance on A has nothing to do with the value of the property in B. you are just saying B also has the X property.